# How to add new type to Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

What is the proper way to add my custom field type, written on Java, extended from Solr's FieldType class?

I've tried to add jar with my type to sole/lib folder, but while creating collection I'm getting

```
HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:Error from server at http://node:8983/solr: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'custom_type_shard1_replica_n1': Unable to create core [custom_type_shard1_replica_n1] Caused by: com.custom.type.Location"
```

In FieldType's `write()` method I just log incoming field for testing purpose.

This is how I define my type an use it in `managed_schema` file:

```
<fieldType name="customlocation" class="com.custom.type.Location"/>
   ...
<field name="location" type="customlocation" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

I've found a couple vvery short tutorials, for example [this](https://javadeveloperzone.com/solr/solr-custom-field-types-definations/) and [this](https://riptutorial.com/solr/example/24544/create-a-custom-solr-field-type-from-own-custom-java-class)

But is there any official and full tutorial about creating and defining custom field type for Solr?

Comment: after adding the jar to lib directory , did you restart the solr before creating/registering the type in solr collection? Also can you please share the complete error stack